# How to match lines of text above and below a certain string up to another string - RegEx

Tags: python, regex

How do I use Regex (python engine) to find a certain string, match several lines above it and all text after it until another specified string? The text is coming from a log file and almost all of the values are dynamic. I have found only one constant string and it sits in the middle of the block I want to capture.
For example:

> Here is a line of text that I DON'T want to match.
>
> Here is a line of text that I DO want to match.
>
> Here is a line of text that I DO want to match.
>
> String to match
>
> Line of text and numbers and other marks abc123:/()& that I want to capture.
>
> Line of text and numbers and other marks abc123:/()& that I want to capture.
>
> Line of text and numbers and other marks abc123:/()& that I want to capture.
>
> String to end on but NOT capture
>
> text I DON'T want
>
> text I DON'T want

I should also probably note that most of these lines can contain not only text but numbers and other punctuation and I need to get all of it. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

EDIT

Here is a real example from the log file with certain values redacted:

```
Tue Oct  0 00:00:00 UTC 0000
A:REDACTED# REDACTED 7/1/8 


==============================================================

Ethernet Interface

===============================================================

Description        : REDACTED

Interface          : 0/0/0                      Oper Speed       : 10 Gbps

Link-level         : Ethernet                   Config Speed     : N/A

Admin State        : up                         Oper Duplex      : full

Oper State         : up                         Config Duplex    : N/A

Physical Link      : Yes                        MTU              : 2004

Single Fiber Mode  : No                         Min Frame Length : 64 Bytes

IfIndex            : REDACTED                  Hold time up     : 90 seconds
```

I need to capture all but the first and last line using "Ethernet Interface" as the text to match.

I have attempted something like this: `(?<=Ethernet Interface)(.*)(?=IfIndex)`
but that only captures the second half of what I need. How do I add in the first part?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't yet tried implementing your own code, please do so first and update where you encountered difficulty. Also actual [MCVE] would help.  [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) is also a great resource.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I updated the original post to include a better example of what I'm working with and my best matching regex so far. I have been using Regex101 and yes, that is a great tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `(?=(.+\n){2}String to match)[\w\W]+(?=String to end on but NOT capture)`

Explanation: it *looks ahead* with `(?=(.+\n){2}String to match)`, which means assure, that what follows are 2 lines `.+\n` (here you need to specify how much lines before the string you want to match) and `String to match`. If it is true, then start matching every character represented by `[\w\W]+`, up to position followed by `String to end but NOT capture`, which is achieved with `(?=String to end on but NOT capture)` (again - positive lookahead).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xgXaQO/1)

Comment: That looks great and is the same direction I was thinking of going but couldn't get to work. I think there is some difference with how it his handling line breaks. Your demo works perfectly but when I try the same thing, it doesn't seem to work the same way. It seems to match everything above it no matter what I change the number to. Here is the demo I am working with : [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1650)

Comment: @MtheBass You turmned `s` option, which enables `.` to match newline. See working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1651).

Comment: That works perfectly! I didn't know that option existed and must have enabled it by mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MtheBass If answer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote it.